# Word problem based on differentiation - a right circular cone.

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, applications

The height of a right circular cone increases by $k\%$, its semi vertical angle remaining constant. Assuming $k$ to be small what is the approximate percentage increase in (i) total surface area (ii) volume?

Answer (score 0):

We have $d(h)/dx=k/100$ now total surface area of cone is  $πr(r+l)$ we get $πr.{\sqrt( r^2+k^2/10000)}$ now volume is $1/3πr^2h$ so  we get$V=1/3πr^{2}k/100=1/300πr^2k$.

Comment: Root is also over $k^2/10000$